# mvc with multilanguage

Tags: php, model-view-controller, multilingual

mvc with multilanguage

the development in MVC, where he is responsible for the translation?
in the controller, in the view, or it can be both?

in controller:
$view-> translate = array (...)

in view:
translate ('word')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

language affects functionality or flow of program? no, then in the view.

Comment: then I'll have something in view how?
translate ('word')

correct?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to apply different process based on the language tt could be in Views only.  In my programs its in the view only.

hth

Comment: are not different processes are unique
I understand that the treatment in view is the best option

thanks